# JWT does not validate Signature with pkcs1v15.go but validates with jwt.io

Tags: go, cryptography, jwt, jwk

This is the issue I am facing,

https://play.golang.org/p/Pq8xHAERD57

If you run the above code, the first token, JWKS pair doesn’t validate the Signature but the second does! But both validate signature in jwt.io. Is there something that can be done with a Golang libarary to validate it?

Now the odd bit is if you take the failing token?
I debugged to find it fails in the function func VerifyPKCS1v15(pub *PublicKey, hash crypto.Hash, hashed []byte, sig []byte) error {

on the lines

```
ok &= subtle.ConstantTimeCompare(em[k-hashLen:k], hashed)
ok &= subtle.ConstantTimeCompare(em[k-tLen:k-hashLen], prefix)
```

Is it something to do with that its Nested tokens?

Both those return -1 (not great with crypto to know why), but it looks like the signature is not right

Failing JWT token:

```
eyJraWQiOiIyMzZjODhkMS01YjUxLTRjZDMtYjczYi1kNmI0YzFmYmUxNzciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.jKehsnGG5j1dOYWlwuF0vKGNbENI1HD35A9g89lhmMrkPhfZ8_lYw4lIkZ16Bepj6HZ53xnTtRXGtmcOZZMr0smh3l5SQ20-CZ6M0yT0wIUZYxJcXmR9_iR7zHI2SvVCpH5CWdlRUNQx9z51Z1SIjc5xvau19omCuMIz7YLZ2Py2tppKz04A8s2xA6Aox-th1dhuKE8NmhTzMnp6UUKbHFyw3Sf7BXJHvQlx4wPB1Pn5l0IZLnD078UsxNmI4r42tECAOmwa0POzzPntlcJNutQZ2QfB68F3YWQZ6YjKF4zTEcZjmMnqVKRLdTyJezGpzXEnitMrnXH-awztlN0d1A
```

Take the key part alone to this website and make a PEM encoded Public key and then run it in jwt.io, the Signature VALIDATES!!!

https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzVoCP5ZRqb/e5Vea/dvu
Nr0NAP/6K+x8Q5iV9ZaSjawp7mqmcDORTgUejrVvLUaeOO+xO4OLHRkqsb75R0VV
IaB/hfTszCjo+CfQ5WUfH9tb3AVUP6bnx/l5VMWVrkYW1YVnaYqrJOD7axS9YXaV
XgEixtHkwqNVLuCJ4Y6S1YxUCJZa4pCCOsPFd0tz4/mNLNUZRJUNuyK4v7AcsIlY
qvl2J/G5cUCKFwSjaRBxPih+pd84dJIktU3xZeyZOMg/G5WiUujoyf20Fx5avLKV
79F31dNBGUIVvu9woQb3mH00IULTJj1HhKjZkyJ16cvkiJ2G1jUk6r4v0cWc652u
ZwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Failing JWT’s JWK:

```
{
    "kty":"RSA",
    "kid":"236c88d1-5b51-4cd3-b73b-d6b4c1fbe177",
    "use":"sig",
    "n":"zVoCP5ZRqb_e5Vea_dvuNr0NAP_6K-x8Q5iV9ZaSjawp7mqmcDORTgUejrVvLUaeOO-xO4OLHRkqsb75R0VVIaB_hfTszCjo-CfQ5WUfH9tb3AVUP6bnx_l5VMWVrkYW1YVnaYqrJOD7axS9YXaVXgEixtHkwqNVLuCJ4Y6S1YxUCJZa4pCCOsPFd0tz4_mNLNUZRJUNuyK4v7AcsIlYqvl2J_G5cUCKFwSjaRBxPih-pd84dJIktU3xZeyZOMg_G5WiUujoyf20Fx5avLKV79F31dNBGUIVvu9woQb3mH00IULTJj1HhKjZkyJ16cvkiJ2G1jUk6r4v0cWc652uZw",
    "e":"AQAB"
}
```

=========================================================
The Second token that successfully validates

```
eyJraWQiOiJlZTJkZWY1Mi1hZmQxLTQxMGUtOWFhOC0wODYzMzYyMzRlOTMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.PTZjUdQ386cC5AloVW5UCXtmHqYZD7zo4JisAjZIQdGowxDR0HfnZ8TEDwb20c7HmYHXUmnP971vYNoI4gEifFWVmiEbiFxKgp1pR68LyqC-qclJApB8jLrMFfSxKiwgKIyLkLqBg6XTGonOVJZcLi3--UD7fiRxj-s-Oq1kH7s3lqyp3-C6oLDHiVZmHfFtOaZQFGFGUhmDCodkMNEGeGm28hyMNZXpB0kgA8FQehEhfMAUe1yHA2hgzONNn4eMAYnVMBb7Ax4pMxHQKbhPP15vU4AOWI4xo1VFZrWtydI9yvFggJu_S_pu5c6Z8PywKMGHZjhh-XaCouVG85Z_PQ
```

Its PEM pub key:

```
 -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhL1hBsWFuD4oXZ6SELvi
bUcv9ap7QDBVZv5BZzGOyjsGmKXumi3UsfAHhhMPC3r9jt6tUsbsp4ahvuBS+9lK
lOk45DtJW4aQRI2k24KAyniwFNweBy1gJny9jrDYHJ7Vot0hkIT86oMqM6gVnbLV
qzrNuQGA+zpB6Crlpzr8z094j7h+KcHTaPJh/qTZq/IUE3xxC0oPfGFYUohWeEjY
Bx7yq3jkMVXEQ9POtcTY9ttNCg9f9MpeNO1la/YMRsiEzJDLEnAtskndTfw6Awad
fN7VZXKHaajFkBulRwZkxo8JusHCQzNWctbfHTYpsvKZBMHTRAjbrTzEE8Ps0x/T
oQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Its JWK:

```
{
   "kty":"RSA",
   "kid":"ee2def52-afd1-410e-9aa8-086336234e93",
   "n":"hL1hBsWFuD4oXZ6SELvibUcv9ap7QDBVZv5BZzGOyjsGmKXumi3UsfAHhhMPC3r9jt6tUsbsp4ahvuBS-9lKlOk45DtJW4aQRI2k24KAyniwFNweBy1gJny9jrDYHJ7Vot0hkIT86oMqM6gVnbLVqzrNuQGA-zpB6Crlpzr8z094j7h-KcHTaPJh_qTZq_IUE3xxC0oPfGFYUohWeEjYBx7yq3jkMVXEQ9POtcTY9ttNCg9f9MpeNO1la_YMRsiEzJDLEnAtskndTfw6AwadfN7VZXKHaajFkBulRwZkxo8JusHCQzNWctbfHTYpsvKZBMHTRAjbrTzEE8Ps0x_ToQ",
   "e":"AQAB"
}
```

Comment: The problem is caused by a bug that has been fixed in the meantime. However, you are using an archived, outdated version of the library https://github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx, which still contains the bug. The correct repository is https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx and here the bug is fixed, see also the answer from lestrrat.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a package for assisting in parsing and validating JWTs when using a JWKS: [`github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc`](https://github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc)

This package is used along with the most popular JWT package, [`github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go).

If you put your JSON Web Keys, JWKs, into a JSON Web Key Set, JWKS, it would look like this:

```json
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "kid": "236c88d1-5b51-4cd3-b73b-d6b4c1fbe177",
      "use": "sig",
      "n": "zVoCP5ZRqb_e5Vea_dvuNr0NAP_6K-x8Q5iV9ZaSjawp7mqmcDORTgUejrVvLUaeOO-xO4OLHRkqsb75R0VVIaB_hfTszCjo-CfQ5WUfH9tb3AVUP6bnx_l5VMWVrkYW1YVnaYqrJOD7axS9YXaVXgEixtHkwqNVLuCJ4Y6S1YxUCJZa4pCCOsPFd0tz4_mNLNUZRJUNuyK4v7AcsIlYqvl2J_G5cUCKFwSjaRBxPih-pd84dJIktU3xZeyZOMg_G5WiUujoyf20Fx5avLKV79F31dNBGUIVvu9woQb3mH00IULTJj1HhKjZkyJ16cvkiJ2G1jUk6r4v0cWc652uZw",
      "e": "AQAB"
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "kid": "ee2def52-afd1-410e-9aa8-086336234e93",
      "n": "hL1hBsWFuD4oXZ6SELvibUcv9ap7QDBVZv5BZzGOyjsGmKXumi3UsfAHhhMPC3r9jt6tUsbsp4ahvuBS-9lKlOk45DtJW4aQRI2k24KAyniwFNweBy1gJny9jrDYHJ7Vot0hkIT86oMqM6gVnbLVqzrNuQGA-zpB6Crlpzr8z094j7h-KcHTaPJh_qTZq_IUE3xxC0oPfGFYUohWeEjYBx7yq3jkMVXEQ9POtcTY9ttNCg9f9MpeNO1la_YMRsiEzJDLEnAtskndTfw6AwadfN7VZXKHaajFkBulRwZkxo8JusHCQzNWctbfHTYpsvKZBMHTRAjbrTzEE8Ps0x_ToQ",
      "e": "AQAB"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a full example of how to parse and validate your JWTs using the JWKS built from your JWKs in the original post:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

const (

    // The two combined JWK from the original post as a JWKS.
    jwksJSON = `{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","kid":"236c88d1-5b51-4cd3-b73b-d6b4c1fbe177","use":"sig","n":"zVoCP5ZRqb_e5Vea_dvuNr0NAP_6K-x8Q5iV9ZaSjawp7mqmcDORTgUejrVvLUaeOO-xO4OLHRkqsb75R0VVIaB_hfTszCjo-CfQ5WUfH9tb3AVUP6bnx_l5VMWVrkYW1YVnaYqrJOD7axS9YXaVXgEixtHkwqNVLuCJ4Y6S1YxUCJZa4pCCOsPFd0tz4_mNLNUZRJUNuyK4v7AcsIlYqvl2J_G5cUCKFwSjaRBxPih-pd84dJIktU3xZeyZOMg_G5WiUujoyf20Fx5avLKV79F31dNBGUIVvu9woQb3mH00IULTJj1HhKjZkyJ16cvkiJ2G1jUk6r4v0cWc652uZw","e":"AQAB"},{"kty":"RSA","kid":"ee2def52-afd1-410e-9aa8-086336234e93","n":"hL1hBsWFuD4oXZ6SELvibUcv9ap7QDBVZv5BZzGOyjsGmKXumi3UsfAHhhMPC3r9jt6tUsbsp4ahvuBS-9lKlOk45DtJW4aQRI2k24KAyniwFNweBy1gJny9jrDYHJ7Vot0hkIT86oMqM6gVnbLVqzrNuQGA-zpB6Crlpzr8z094j7h-KcHTaPJh_qTZq_IUE3xxC0oPfGFYUohWeEjYBx7yq3jkMVXEQ9POtcTY9ttNCg9f9MpeNO1la_YMRsiEzJDLEnAtskndTfw6AwadfN7VZXKHaajFkBulRwZkxo8JusHCQzNWctbfHTYpsvKZBMHTRAjbrTzEE8Ps0x_ToQ","e":"AQAB"}]}`
)

func main() {

    // Create the JWKS from hardcoded JSON.
    //
    // This can also be done via an HTTPS resource using the keyfunc.Get function.
    jwks, err := keyfunc.New([]byte(jwksJSON))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create JWKS from JSON.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }

    // The "failing" JWT from the original post.
    jwtB64 := "eyJraWQiOiIyMzZjODhkMS01YjUxLTRjZDMtYjczYi1kNmI0YzFmYmUxNzciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.jKehsnGG5j1dOYWlwuF0vKGNbENI1HD35A9g89lhmMrkPhfZ8_lYw4lIkZ16Bepj6HZ53xnTtRXGtmcOZZMr0smh3l5SQ20-CZ6M0yT0wIUZYxJcXmR9_iR7zHI2SvVCpH5CWdlRUNQx9z51Z1SIjc5xvau19omCuMIz7YLZ2Py2tppKz04A8s2xA6Aox-th1dhuKE8NmhTzMnp6UUKbHFyw3Sf7BXJHvQlx4wPB1Pn5l0IZLnD078UsxNmI4r42tECAOmwa0POzzPntlcJNutQZ2QfB68F3YWQZ6YjKF4zTEcZjmMnqVKRLdTyJezGpzXEnitMrnXH-awztlN0d1A"

    // Parse the JWT.
    var token *jwt.Token
    if token, err = jwt.Parse(jwtB64, jwks.KeyFunc); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to parse \"failing\" JWT from original post.\nError: %s", err.Error())
        // TODO Exit program.
    } else {

        // Confirm the token is valid.
        if !token.Valid {
            log.Println(`The "failing" token from the original post is not valid.`)
        }
    }

    // The second token from the original post.
    jwtB64 = "eyJraWQiOiJlZTJkZWY1Mi1hZmQxLTQxMGUtOWFhOC0wODYzMzYyMzRlOTMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.PTZjUdQ386cC5AloVW5UCXtmHqYZD7zo4JisAjZIQdGowxDR0HfnZ8TEDwb20c7HmYHXUmnP971vYNoI4gEifFWVmiEbiFxKgp1pR68LyqC-qclJApB8jLrMFfSxKiwgKIyLkLqBg6XTGonOVJZcLi3--UD7fiRxj-s-Oq1kH7s3lqyp3-C6oLDHiVZmHfFtOaZQFGFGUhmDCodkMNEGeGm28hyMNZXpB0kgA8FQehEhfMAUe1yHA2hgzONNn4eMAYnVMBb7Ax4pMxHQKbhPP15vU4AOWI4xo1VFZrWtydI9yvFggJu_S_pu5c6Z8PywKMGHZjhh-XaCouVG85Z_PQ"

    // Parse the JWT.
    if token, err = jwt.Parse(jwtB64, jwks.KeyFunc); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to parse the second token from the original post.\nError: %s", err.Error())
        // TODO Exit program.
    } else {

        // Confirm the token is valid.
        if !token.Valid {
            log.Println("The second token from the original post is not valid.")
        }
    }

}
```